# R - Generating dynamic text for Select Argument in Subset Function

Tags: r, arguments

I'm having a problem with using subset() inside a function I'm writing.

```
myFun <- function(arg1="", arg2="", arg3="")

{
    temp.frame <- subset(master.frame, a == arg1 & b == arg2 & c == arg3)

}
```

This works fine if specifies all arguments, but if any one or more of the arguments isn't specified subset function doesn't work properly (as it look for missing values in column vector passed with null values in function calling)

I want it to work such that if an argument is not specified, it is not included in what subset() goes looking for.

So if I were to input:

```
function1(arg2=5, arg3=6)  then in function1, the subset command will look like
temp.frame <- subset(master.frame, b == 5 & c == 6)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please suggest if any alternate to this solution instead of using subset function.

Comment: Is function1 in the example the same as myFun?
If I understood what you want to do, I think you should avoid initialising the arguments first i.e. `myFun <- function(arg1, arg2, arg3)`and then just test if the arguments have been initialised at the call.

Comment: And I am not sure the question is a good description of what you want